# How to find upper bound on regret of stochastic linear bandit not pseudo-regret

Tags: lg.learning, online-learning, reinforcement-learning

In stochastic linear bandit we assume that the reward at each period is generated from $r_t= x_t^\top \theta + \varepsilon_t$ where $\varepsilon_t$ is R-sub-Gaussian. Based on this definition, we define pseudo-regret which is $\sum_{t=1}^{T}x_*^\top \theta - x_t \theta$. We can determine a confidence interval for $\theta$ at each period such that $\|\hat{\theta_t}-\theta\|_V$ contains the true parameter vector with high probability. So, we define the pseudo-regret as $Tx_*^\top \theta -\sum_{t=1}^Tx_t^\top \theta$. In pseudo-regret, the random noise has been neglected. I am wondering how it is possible to consider the exact regret and what procedure should be used to find an upper bound for regret.

As a similar question, suppose we define sets $S$ and $S^c$ such that $S \cap S^c=  \emptyset$ and $S \cup S^c = \{1,2,\dots,T\}$, how can we find an upper bound on $\sum_{t \in S}r_t -\sum_{t\prime \in S^c} r_{t^\prime}$ where we consider observed rewards not expected rewards.